# MySQL CREATE/DROP USER returns 0

Tags: mysql, pdo, mariadb

Why is it that

```
$dbh->exec(CREATE USER 'usr'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Pass100');
```

returns 0 even though the user is created?  This is with MariaDB 10.

Comment: _"PDO::exec() returns the number of rows that were modified or deleted by the SQL statement you issued. If no rows were affected, PDO::exec() returns 0."_  So my assumption is that a `CREATE USER` statement is one which does not affect any rows, despite possibly modifying the `mysql` database implicitly. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php

Comment: I guess this should be an answer. Hang on and I'll post it below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the PDO docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php), `PDO::exec()` returns the number of rows modified or deleted, or zero if none were.

> PDO::exec() returns the number of rows that were modified or deleted by the SQL statement you issued. If no rows were affected, PDO::exec() returns 0

A `CREATE USER/DROP USER` statement, although it implicitly modifies the `mysql.user` table does not register as having affected any rows as an `INSERT` or `DELETE` statement would, and so `exec()` returns zero.

For example from the command line:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE USER u@localhost;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> DROP USER u@localhost;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

So the `0` return value should not be treated as a failure or falsy value. In other words, be careful **not to use** an expression like:

```
// Do not do this:
if (!$dbh->exec("CREATE USER 'usr'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Pass100'")) {
  // Handle error
}
```

Instead use a strict comparison `===` to test for a `FALSE` return:

```
if ($dbh->exec("CREATE USER 'usr'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Pass100'") === FALSE) {
  // Handle error
}
```

If there is any error in creating the user, such as the user already exists or you lack the privileges to create it, MariaDB will report that as an error, causing `PDO::exec()` to return `FALSE` instead of integer `0`, or throw an exception if you have configured `$dbh` for `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`.

Comment: @MichelBerkowski - thanks for the comprehensive answer.